# Visual Studio 2010 Migration Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I installed VS 2010 on my Win XP SP3 machine and...

1. Created a C# Dll project
2. Compiled and it works fine
3. Added a resx file to the project and added a few images to it
4. Compiled and now it gives the following error.

```
    --------------------------Compile Error-----------------------------
    The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
    System.InvalidOperationException: The security state of an AppDomain was modified by an AppDomainManager configured with the NoSecurityChanges flag.
       at System.AppDomain.SetupDomainSecurity(AppDomainHandle appDomain, ObjectHandleOnStack appDomainEvidence, IntPtr creatorsSecurityDescriptor, Boolean publishAppDomain)
       at System.AppDomain.InitializeDomainSecurity(Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo, Boolean generateDefaultEvidence, IntPtr parentSecurityDescriptor, Boolean publishAppDomain)
       at System.AppDomain.Setup(Object arg)
       at System.AppDomain.nCreateDomain(String friendlyName, AppDomainSetup setup, Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo, IntPtr parentSecurityDescriptor)
       at System.AppDomainManager.CreateDomainHelper(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)
       at System.AppDomainManager.CreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)
       at System.AppDomain.InternalCreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup info)
       at System.AppDomain.CreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup info)
       at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult) TestClassLibrary
```

I then tried...

1. Adding the following to devenv.exe.config, Machine.config

```
<runtime>
        <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy  enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

1. Adding the following under the first property group in the Project file.

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>true</GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>
    </ProjectGroup>
```

Still no luck.  Is it problem with my VS installation?  I already repaired it once.

Answer (score 2):

app.config settings:

`<runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
     <legacyCasPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>`

worked for me

Koto

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same problems, and just repairing Visual Studio 2010 didn't solve the problem.

However, the problems disappeared after I've retreated to removing Visual Studio fully and reinstalling it. Worth a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Visual Studio Installation folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

and have following entry in "devenv.exe.config" file.

```
<runtime><NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy  enabled="false"/></runtime>
```