# XSL Transformation fails in VS2010 when NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xslt

I recently upgraded a VS2008 project to VS2010.  This is a rather large legacy project, passed through many developer hands but with ongoing development.

It uses Devexpress 9.1 and after the upgrade all Forms\Controls refused to load at design time with a message about "Explicitly us[ing] CAS policy, which is obsolete" - this was fixed by adding the following to devenv.exe.config file:

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

Unfortunately this seems to have an unintended effect in that it broke XSL Transforms in the project. The project also uses a custom ORM system, apparently developed just before Entity-Framework became popular (why they didn't use nHibernate I'm not sure, but the original developers apparently decided they could do a better job themselves)  So it consists of a huge XML file defining the Objects and a large XSLT file to transform this into a cs file.

But after adding the above NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy switch now running the XSL Tranform (by just selecting the XSLT file and using "CTRL-ALT+F5") results in the following error:

```
The security state of an AppDomain was modified by an AppDomainManager configured with the NoSecurityChanges flag.
```

Removing the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy flag fixes this but breaks all Forms\Controls again.

Anybody have any idea how I can use XSL transformation in Visual Studio 2010 with the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled?

EDIT:

Even worse, it seems that having this enabled breaks all MVC tooling in visual studio with the same error message. e.g. I can no longer add MVC views. Ouch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 Migration Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937736/visual-studio-2010-migration-issue)